Extract figure URLs with Bio Entrez
How do I extract figure URLs with Bio Entrez?
Target URL
https://cdn.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/blobs/d5dd/11665554/5f64f8cca9f2/jciinsight-9-186078-g078.jpg
Breakdown

https://cdn.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/blobs/ [base URL]
d5dd [blob ID?]
11665554 [PMCID]
5f64f8cca9f2 [??]
jciinsight-9-186078-g078.jpg [XLink]

XLink
from Bio import Entrez
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with Entrez.efetch(db='pmc', id=11665554) as handle:
    content = handle.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features='xml')

figure = soup.find('graphic')
figure.attrs['xlink:href'] # jciinsight-9-186078-g077

My question
What I want to know is: where did d5dd and 5f64f8cca9f2 come from? I don't see these strings anywhere in the XML, and they change from paper to paper.

Original paper: https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC11665554
